# Building Generic Search Expression - InvalidOperationException: Coalesce used with type that cannot be null

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I am having an issue building a generic search expression that will work on multiple different types of objects.  The problem I am running into is that some properties will contain a null value.

What this function will do is call the ToString method on each property and see if it contains the search value for that particular property.  The problem is, if it is Null the.  If I try to Coalesce it throws the `InvalidOperationException: Coalesce used with type that cannot be null` exception.

Here is a simple class:

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public int IntValue { get; set; }
  public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    //Generate data
    var list = (new List<SomeObject>
    {
      new SomeObject { IntValue = 5, StringValue = "abc" },
      new SomeObject { IntValue = 10, StringValue = "abc" },
      new SomeObject { IntValue = 10 },
      new SomeObject { StringValue = "xyz" },
      new SomeObject()
    }).AsQueryable<SomeObject>();

    var searchValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IntValue", "5"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("StringValue", "abc")
    };

    var whereExp = GenerateSearchExpression<SomeObject>(searchValues);
    var asdf = list.Where(whereExp).ToList();

    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  }

  static Expression<Func<SomeObject, bool>> GenerateSearchExpression<dataType>(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
  {      
    //Get the properties of the data type
    var objectType = typeof(dataType);
    var objProps = objectType.GetProperties();

    Expression whereExpr = Expression.Constant(true);
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeObject), "val");

    //Cycle through each property
    foreach (var searchValue in values)
    {
      var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, searchValue.Key);
      var emptyString = Expression.Constant("");

      //InvalidOperationException: Coalesce used with type that cannot be null
      var coalesceExpr = Expression.Coalesce(propExpr, emptyString);

      var toStringExpr = Expression.Call(coalesceExpr, "ToString", new Type[0]);
      var toLowerExpr = Expression.Call(toStringExpr, "ToLower", new Type[0]);
      var containExpr = Expression.Call(toLowerExpr, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(searchValue.Value));

      //Add this to the exisiting where expression.
      whereExpr = Expression.And(whereExpr, containExpr);
    }

    var foobar = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeObject, bool>>(whereExpr, paramExpr);

    return foobar;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I needed up using the `propExpr.Type.IsValueType` property:

Here is the final function:

```
  static Expression<Func<SomeObject, bool>> GenerateSearchExpression<dataType>(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
  {      
    //Get the properties of the data type
    var objectType = typeof(dataType);
    var objProps = objectType.GetProperties();

    Expression whereExpr = Expression.Constant(true);
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeObject), "val");

    MethodCallExpression toStringExpr;
    foreach (var searchValue in values)
    {
      var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, searchValue.Key);

      if (propExpr.Type.IsValueType == true)
      {
        toStringExpr = Expression.Call(propExpr, "ToString", new Type[0]);
      }
      else
      {
        var emptyString = Expression.Constant("");
        var coalesceExpr = Expression.Coalesce(propExpr, emptyString);
        toStringExpr = Expression.Call(coalesceExpr, "ToString", new Type[0]);            
      }

      var toLowerExpr = Expression.Call(toStringExpr, "ToLower", new Type[0]);
      var containExpr = Expression.Call(toLowerExpr, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(searchValue.Value));         

      //Add this to the exisiting where expression.
      whereExpr = Expression.And(whereExpr, containExpr);
    }

    var foobar = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeObject, bool>>(whereExpr, paramExpr);

    return foobar;
  }
```